# RC5 алгоритм на PHP

Tags: php, криптография

Встала задача написать функцию хеширования в формате RC5 на PHP. Помогите пожалуйста нарыть какие нибудь наработки на эту тему. Может у кого есть готовый код, поделитесь пожалуйста.

> RC5 (Ron’s Code 5 или Rivest’s Cipher 5) — это блочный шифр,
>   разработанный Роном Ривестом из компании RSA Security Inc. с
>   переменным количеством раундов, длиной блока и длиной ключа. Это
>   расширяет сферу использования и упрощает переход на более сильный
>   вариант алгоритма.

Comment: Ребята, ну неужели никто не поможет?( Завтра зачет сдавать((

Comment: [Вот RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2040.txt).

Просто переведите Си на ПХП.

Comment: @axejko увы я не спец по похапэ так что не помощник...

Comment: Сделал на с++. Сдал на 4!) Всем спасибо! =)